# How can all the data points be extracted from a graph of an implicit function which is plotted using Contourplot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, data, implicit

I have a plot of an implicit function. I would like to extract all the data points from the graph. The plot is done using contourplot and cannot be plot with plot command.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4):

Here a random example plot:

```
plot = ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Surfaces in such plots are usually represented by `GraphicsComplex`es in compressed notation. The first entry in such a `GraphicsComplex` is always the list of vertex coordinates (followed by specifications of `Polygon`s via a list of integer tuples, wrapped in `Polygon`).

We can extract a list of all `GraphicsComplex`es from a plot with

```
gclist = Cases[plot, _GraphicsComplex, \[Infinity]];
```

In this case, there is only one `GraphicsComplex`, so `gclist` has length 1. The vertex positions can thus be obtained with `gclist[[1, 1]]` as in the following example

```
Graphics3D[Point[gclist[[1, 1]]]]
```

[image]